# Bigcommerce: edit an existing order shipment address

Tags: api, bigcommerce, http-put

I imported 10k legacy orders with the wrong state. How do I fix it? When I use the order shipment update endpoint `PUT /orders/{order_id}/shipments/{id}` I get an error that the shipping_address field is not writable. What do I do?

I'm using the API docs here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/order-shipments/putordersorderidshipmentsid

Comment: This is a fantastic question. I wish this had been spelled out in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to directly write to the order shipment address state field, but for context, that mirrors the behavior you'd see when working with order shipments in the control panel. The best solution would be to delete the shipments with the incorrect state and re-create the shipments.

**Edit:**
There are 2 options to re-create the shipment with the correct address: The first is to update the order by adding a new shipping address containing the correct state and use that shipping address when you re-make the shipment. Although existing order shipping addresses can't be edited, the order shipping address array is additive. So you can [update the order](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/orders/putordersid) by adding a new shipping address and use that order_address_id to create the new shipment. The second option would be to delete the entire order with the incorrect shipping address and re-import it with the correct data, then re-create the shipment.

On the orders resource, we are scoping a feature request to make shipping addresses editable. (This would align with what you're able to do when editing an order through the control panel). I'll keep you posted in this thread when there's an update on that, although the best solution in the meantime would be to use one of the options outlined above.

Comment: Thanks @Karen White - but [these docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/order-shipments/postordersorderidshipments) say that the shipping address is read-only.  If I delete all my shipments, will I be able to create new ones with an address?

Comment: That's a good clarification @WillardSolutions--yes, you'll be able to create new shipments, but the address will still pull from the order that originates the shipment. I'll edit my answer with more detail, because it's a little lengthy for a comment.

Comment: Thanks @karen for the update. One more question - it [seems](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/orders/deleteorders) that deleting an order doesn't _really_ delete it, but instead archives it. Is that correct?  Is there any way to totally delete an old, erroneous order?

Comment: @WillardSolutions You're correct--orders are not permanently deleted; they go into a state called archived that removes them from the control panel view. It's not possible to completely delete old orders.

Comment: The endpoints for deleting order shipments seem to have no effect.  DELETE /orders/{order_id}/shipments/{id} and DELETE /orders/{order_id}/shipments [docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/order-shipments/deleteordersorderidshipmentsid) both return 204 responses but the shipments are still viewable in the store. The POST /orders/{order_id}/shipments endpoint correctly adds new shipments.  Can you confirm the DELETE endpoints for order shipments are functional?

Comment: That's odd, I can confirm that both endpoints work correctly when I test on my end. After refreshing the page, the deleted shipments are removed from the control panel. If you do a GET request for the shipment that was just deleted, do you get a 404 or does it return the shipment?

Comment: I just hit the order shipment delete all endpoint  using the sample request tool on the [docs page](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/order-shipments/deleteordersorderidshipments).  Got a 204 response, and when I GET the order shipments, I also get an empty 204.  But on the [control panel](https://mybeautymart.mybigcommerce.com/manage/orders) I click on the order, and all of the shipments (in the center column when I expand an order) are still there. Am I missing something? How do I get rid those "shipments"?

Comment: There are 2 places that an order shipment will show in the control panel: under Orders>View here: https://screencast.com/t/1Dyny711fv and also under Orders>Shipments. I'm seeing both of those removed when I delete a shipment through the API. The order status would need to be changed separately if desired. Are you trying to edit a different area? The center column in the order view screen would be the shipping address.

Comment: So Karen, in the screenshot you shared, I want to change the middle column (Shipping). I can add a new address there, but when I try to delete the order shipment (right column), the shipment does not go away, and the original/wrong shipping address still shows the items have been sent to that address. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @WillardSolutions The actions that you take with the shipment object won't have any effect on the shipping address(es) associated with the order object (what's showing in the middle column). A shipment represents the order items that have been sent to a particular shipping address--it's a separate entity from the order shipping address. To edit the shipping address(es) associated with the order, you can either add additional addresses with a PUT to /order/id as mentioned above, or you can archive the order and re-import it with the correct info.

Comment: Then I guess my question is - what practical use does the DELETE order shipment endpoint have then? If I can't delete a shipment from an order/address and re-add that shipment elsewhere it seems pretty useless.  Am I misunderstanding the purpose of this endpoint?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand here: `I can't delete a shipment from an order/address and re-add that shipment elsewhere`. A shipment=a group of order products + an address selected from the order shipping address array + a shipping carrier. So the shipment object is made up of elements from the original order (i.e. the order address and the order products) but doesn't alter those elements. You might use the delete shipment endpoint if you were building a shipping label printing solution and needed to re-do a shipment with different products or a different address from the shipping address array.

Comment: And when I add a shipment, it adds a new shipping address to the center column, but when I delete a shipment, it does not delete anything from the center column on the order control panel. It just seems to me that this part of the API is terribly counter-intuitive.